# Неадекватное поведение BottomSheet

Tags: java, android

При инициализации BottomSheet оно частично отображается снизу экрана, далее при попытке подтащить его к верху, что бы оно полностью отобразилось, оно соскальзывает и исчезает.  Как это исправить? Или как сделать, что бы появлялся сразу весь BottomSheet на экране?

Видео, как это выглядит: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58bhlc-KfYA&feature=youtu.be

код Активити:

```
public class FirstscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener,
        ItemAdapter.ItemListener {

    private BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
    private ItemAdapter mAdapterItem;
    private FloatingActionButton floatButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);


        mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, this));

        mList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        floatButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.float_button);
        floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showBottomSheetDialog();
            }
        });

        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet;
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
            }
        });
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapterItem = new ItemAdapter(createItems(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterItem);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) mList.getAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
        if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }

        mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet, null);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(createItems(), new ItemAdapter.ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                if (mBottomSheetDialog != null) {
                    mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }));

        mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
        mBottomSheetDialog.show();
        mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mBottomSheetDialog = null;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAdapterItem.setListener(null);
    }

    public List<Item> createItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.camera, "from new shoots"));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.folder_multiple_image, "from ready images"));
        return items;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Item item) {
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }
}
```

Адаптер  RecyclerView для BottomSheet:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mItems;
    private ItemListener mListener;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items, ItemListener listener) {
        mItems = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setListener(ItemListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(mItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public Item item;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        public void setData(Item item) {
            this.item = item;
            imageView.setImageResource(item.getDrawableResource());
            textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick(Item item);
    }
}
```

xml активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#118b0a"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_white" />


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml RecyclerView Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте указать следующее:

```
mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло! Правда вместо mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP) использовала mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM) и получила, как раз то что хотела!

Comment: @Lucky_girl рад был помочь!:)